# Is "make a queue/ line" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I was in a meeting with my colleagues here in Canada and we went for coffee...more and more people joined and there was only one coffee machine. So, I said **"let's make a queue"**...then a colleague of mine said **"let's queue up"**.

Now I am wondering if "making a queue" is at all correct?

Comment: Make a queue is not idiomatic. *Let’s wait in a queue* or *queue up* as suggested by your colleague. *Form a line* can be used also as well as *Let's stand on line, let's get in line.*

Comment: "Make a line" sounds fine to me, but I only know about American English, which doesn't use "queue" here.

Comment: Make a queue ... If I am coding for computer, and I write code that will cause a digital construct called a "queue" to occur, perhaps I am "making a queue".

Comment: *Make a queue* sounds OK to me in UK English, although not the most natural, but it would probably mean to form people into a queue. To *queue up* can mean to join an existing queue, or stand behind someone to form a queue, so it has slightly different usage.

Comment: "Form a queue" works well in UK English too, if possibly slightly formal (no pun intended).

Comment: @psmears Yes, *form* a line or queue in uk.